# How to join by two fields showing the not matching records and group by using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

In `Visual Studio 2013`, `C# 4.5`, I have these classes:

**Entities:**

```
public class KpiLabourHoursByTeamRole
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public double TotalHours { get; set; }
    public double TotalCost { get; set; }
}

public class TeamRole
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int RoleId { get; set;}
    public int TeamId { get; set;}
    public int? LabourCostCenterId { get; set; }
}

public class KpiLabourHoursByCostCenter
{
   public int? LabourCostCenterId { get; set; }
   public double TotalHours { get; set; }
   public double TotalCost { get; set; }
}
```

**Current Solution:**

Currently, I have the solution below working perfectly as a `Inner Join` using `Linq`:

`kpiLabourHours` is a object of the type: `KpiLabourHoursByTeamRole`

`kpiLabourHoursByCostCenter` is a object of the type: `KpiLabourHoursByCostCenter`

```
var kpiLabourHoursByCostCenter = from k in kpiLabourHours
    join tr in teamRoles on new {k.TeamId, k.RoleId} equals new {tr.TeamId, tr.RoleId}
    group k by new { tr.LabourCostCenterId }
    into grp
    select new KpiLabourHoursByCostCenter
    {
        LabourCostCenterId = grp.Key.LabourCostCenterId,
        TotalHours = grp.Sum(k => k.TotalHours),
        TotalCost = grp.Sum(k => k.TotalCost),
    };
```

**Equivalent in Sql:**

The code above is represented by the equivalent `Sql`:

```
SELECT tr.LabourCostCenterId, sum(k.TotalHours), sum(k.TotalCost)
FROM kpiLabourHours k
INNER JOIN TeamRoles tr on tr.TeamId = k.TeamId and tr.RoleId = k.RoleId  
GROUP tr.LabourCostCenterId
```

**My problem:**

The problem is that it is hidding the results where there is no matching `TeamId` and `RoleId`, so I need to replace this code by a kind of `Left Outer Join`, such as:

```
SELECT tr.LabourCostCenterId, sum(k.TotalHours), sum(k.TotalCost)
FROM kpiLabourHours k
LEFT OUTER JOIN TeamRoles tr on tr.TeamId = k.TeamId and tr.RoleId = k.RoleId  
GROUP tr.LabourCostCenterId
```

In a nutshell, I need to return `LabourCostCenter NULL` or `0` if there is no matching `TeamId` and `RoleId` with the totals.

Comment: @antlersoft I tried but I couldn't understand that one, could you help me with the solution, would apreciate :)

Comment: @antlersoft I am struggling here to make it work, I tried 20 examples, my case is slightly different, I have group by two fields, this website is suposed to help specific problems also. thanks

Comment: Well, you should have linked it, and told exactly what you didn't understand about it. You can still do that! (Even if it would already have been closed, that wouldn't be the end unless you let it be the end.) Aside:: I probably won't be able to help you with an answer, not my bailwick.

Comment: @Deduplicator I appreciate your attention, you are a legend, and I have great news I made it work!! Is it something useful to post the solution in this post? Thanks

Comment: Great news. Well, it's your decision whether posting a new answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq, polishing (one or more) answers there, or posting a new answer here would be the better contribution to SO. I just don't know.